# CPU upgrade for heavy IDE (Visual Studio)

Tags: performance, processor

In next months i am thinking about upgrade my pc workstation.

I am thinking about 2 models:

- intel i7 8700k: less cores but better performance by one core
- amd ryzen 1800x: more core but less performance by one core.

Well, question is which cpu is better for heavy IDE (Visual Studio) ?

I am not aiming for speed up build time, but speed up overall IDE responsivity. (Lot of projects with resharper plugin installed for example)

Thanks for advice

Comment: Welcome to Hardware Recommendations. We need a bit more information: 1.) Do you have a budget? Price/performance is important. 2.) The IDE probably isn't the slowest part of development. What type of development do you do? If you are doing some machine learning, a GPU may be more appropriate than a CPU update, etc. 3.) RAM is another reason an IDE can be sluggish. Do you have enough in your current system? 4.) What mother board do you have? That's your most important factor - especially if you aren't going to be upgrading that as well.

Comment: Hello and thanks for redirecting. Budget is about 400$  +-. Most time i use Visual Studio for develop "line of business aplications",sometime mobile (Xamarin).  My current hardware is  i5-4690k, 16gb ram and nvidia gtx 1700 . Anyway new cpu need new motherboard and ddr4 ram, so it will be upgrade too. Thanks for answer

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/44926/building-a-fast-visual-studio-machine as well as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814015/was-visual-studio-2008-2010-or-2012-v11-written-to-use-multi-cores and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054410/does-visual-studio-2012-utilize-all-available-cpu-cores

Answer (score 1):

I'll like to go with Intel i7 8700k. Intel processors are more developer friendly. Supports more Advanced technologies like

- VT-x
- Turbo boost
- Intel Optane

Intel supports more development technologies than AMD. And you will not see the performance difference regardless of processor you choose. You should use the latest SSD. Install the OS and Visual Studio on SSD. That will increase your IDE response time a lot.

Comment: Your first two "more Advanced" technologies have functionally equivalent AMD counterparts. The last is of dubious value. Getting a SSD though, I definitely agree with.

Comment: Install VS and OS to ssd is basic. Maybe i thinking about switch sata ssd to pcie ssd. But not sure about performance boost. Anyway ty for answer.